# Code to Start and Stop a broadcasting script on a schedule

Tags: html

I am somewhat new to coding.

I work for a sports complex and I have set up live streaming.

Currently I have to manually go into the streaming platform and click "start broadcasting" and "stop broadcasting" when I want those things to happen.

I am wondering if I can add code to the HTML to do these functions automatically on a scheduled timer I specify?

Thanks,
Jade

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not specific, but I am going to assume you have javascript functions defined somewhere that can start and stop broadcasting. Something like this:

```
function startBroadcasting() {
 // do whatever it takes to start broadcasting
}

function stopBroadcasting() {
 // do whatever it takes to stop broadcasting
}
```

What you need then, is to call, in a script tag at the bottom of the body, something like this:

```
var running = false;

function myScheduler() {
    var now = new Date();
    var dow = now.getDay();
    var hr = now.getHours();
    var min = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();

    if (dow === 6 && hr === 7 && min === 0 && !running) {
        setTimeout(startBroadcasting, 0);
    }

    if (dow === 9 && hr === 21 && min === 0 && running) {
        setTimeout(stopBroadcasting, 0);
    }
}

setInterval(myScheduler, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes I see inside the code that the player does use javascript. So lets say I want the streams to start broadcasting every Saturday morning at 7am and stop broadcasting every Sunday night at 9pm.

Do you have an example code that would make this happen?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a built-in event scheduling mechanism like that. What you could do, is create a function that runs every 1s and has the start/stop logic in it. I will update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: So am i only editing the red numbers? What do I put in for the date format?

Answer (score 0):

The embedded code for the player on the website is below. Where and how would I implement the schedule into this?

```
<!--SVP embed code begin-->
<div id="svp_player5zen1ooango4" style="width:720px;height:405px;position:relative;">
    <a class="svp_embed_link" style="color:#000;cursor:default;" href="http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/how_to_create_tv_channel.html" title="create tv channel" >create tv channel</a>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://play.streamingvideoprovider.com/js/dplayer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
var vars = {clip_id:"5zen1ooango4",transparent:"false",pause:"1",repeat:"",bg_color:"#FFFFFF",fs_mode:"2",no_controls:"",start_img:"1",start_volume:"100",close_button:"",brand_new_window:"1",auto_hide:"1",stretch_video:"",player_align:"NONE",offset_x:"",offset_y:"",player_color_ratio:0.6,skinAlpha:"80",colorBase:"#202020",colorIcon:"#FFFFFF",colorHighlight:"#fcad37",direct:"true",is_responsive:"false",viewers_limit:0,cc_position:"bottom",cc_positionOffset:70,cc_multiplier:0.03,cc_textColor:"#ffffff",cc_textOutlineColor:"#000000",cc_bkgColor:"#000000",cc_bkgAlpha:0.7};
var svp_player = new SVPDynamicPlayer("svp_player5zen1ooango4", "", "720", "405", {use_div:"svp_player5zen1ooango4",skin:"3"}, vars);
svp_player.execute();
//-->
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript! JavaScript is needed to display this video player.</noscript>
<!--SVP embed code end-->
```

Comment: It is not related with the embed code.

First of all you need an back-end script which can authorize with your API credentials and start/stop your broadcast. This part should be easy and if you use php you can copy/paste their [example code](http://www.streamingvideoprovider.co.uk/docs/api/SVP_API_Examples.zip).

The schedule can be configured with cron jobs. A good tutorial can be found in [Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see form their page StreamingVideoProvider has an API to control your broadcast, which is explained [here](http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/kb/index.php/article/api).

First of all you need to get an access token by requesting the `svp_auth_get_token` service.
After that you can start/stop your broadcast by calling `svp_start_broadcast`/`svp_stop_broadcast` where you need to pass your token and the video ID (in your case it's `5zen1ooango4`).

At the top of the API docs there is an download link for some example code which may help you.